# Is there a way to turn an FPDF output into a URL?

Tags: php, pdf, google-drive-api, fpdf

I created a pdf using FPDF in php. I want to have the website automatically upload this pdf to Google Drive through the API. However, seeing that this is not a file on the PC, can I turn the pdf into a url?
For instance, something like: http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
$fpdf->Output('F', 'Path to file');
```

It can be found in the [documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm).

Save the file to a publicly accessible folder and echo the url to the user.